# Common mode noise from two ADC results

Tags: discrete-signals, noise, signal-analysis

I am sampling two sinusoidal analogue signals that are phase separated by $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, and there appears to be a significant amount of common mode noise in my samples. What, if any approach can I take to improve my SNR?

Comment: Are the analog sources and ADC's properly grounded/isolated/terminated?

Comment: No, I don't think they are. I don't have control over the physical board and ADCs only the software so I am trying my best to fix the real problem in software.